# RuntimeException You need to specify a file path to store the seed. laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel-4, dompdf

After i update my composer this error showed "You need to specify a file path to store the seed".
I've tried many solutions but they are not successful.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to enable php_openssl in your php.ini file to fix this issue.

Uncomment the following line in your php.ini file:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: I am using wamp. i've uncomment the extension=php_openssl.dll on php.ini on wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12. But still it showed the same error.